# Creating If/Else based on URL of page

Tags: php, url, if-statement

Basically what I'm trying to do is create an if/else statement based on the URL of the current site im on. The if/else statement is going to echo a list based on an alphabetical range. So in other words, If the url starts with letters between (A-G) I want it to echo one thing, and if it starts with letters (H-Z) I want it to echo something else. This script will be used on many websites. Thanks

Comment: You can access any character of a string with `[]` syntax, for instance `$string='foobar';echo $string[0];` yields 'f'.

Comment: thanks @Wrikken, so does that mean I could create a string like so: $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; and then use $url[11] to get the letter?

Comment: Is there anyway that I could make it get the first letter after www.

Comment: Yes, it does mean that, but if you want to match after a certain string, I'd rather use `substr($string,strpos($string,'www.')+4,1);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
    $uri = strtoupper(isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) ? $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] : '/CLI');
    if(ord($uri[1]) <= ord('G'))
        echo "Echo one thing";
    else
        echo "Echo something else";
```

Comment: I think this will definitely work as I had wanted it to do. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

look into $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']

Comment: Thanks @Keith, Thats exactly what I was hoping on using, but I don't know how to do the second part which is to check to see what the first letter of the url is and then echo something based on that.